# Ignoring generic type argument when the specifity is not needed in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Suppose I have a class with an elaborate generic type argument like

```js
class SomeStuff<T extends ElaborateStuff> {...}
```

Elsewhere I have a function with a `SomeStuff` parameter like

```js
function doSimpleThings(stuff: SomeStuff<X>): void {...}
```

which is independent of the specific incarnation of `X` as an extension of `ElaborateStuff`. The above is complained about by the compiler, because `X` must extend `ElaborateStuff`. I could write

```js
function doSimpleThings(stuff: SomeStuff<any>): void {...}
```

but then eslint complains about the explicit use of `any`. Is there another way than switching off the `any` warning? In Java I would use `<?>`, is there a similar syntax in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no `?` syntax in typescript. It really depends on the variance of your generic type if you can use anything except `any`, but you probably will use `any` classes usually end up being invariant.

At it's core this is a question of variance. If you want to know more on that you can check out my talk [here](https://youtu.be/EInunOVRsUU)

If the class is co-varinat you can use `ElaborateStuff` and any instantiation of `SomeStuff` will be compatible with it as `SomeStuff<ElaborateStuff>` will be the base class of all instantiations:

```
type ElaborateStuff = {
    a: string
}
class SomeStuff<T extends ElaborateStuff> {
    getVStuff(): T {
        return null!;
    }
}

function doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(stuff: SomeStuff<ElaborateStuff>): void { }


doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); //OK
doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>()); // OK

function doSimpleThingsNever(stuff: SomeStuff<never>): void { }
doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // Error 
doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>()); // Error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNgQwEYHsBODgQMrAK4BmBUAvFAN4BQUNUCAXFAM7BoCWAdgOaUC+lAY0RMmUbCgC2OfEQA8AFSgQAHlg4ATUfGTpM0wgQB8FarS4RgANVwGAFAEpGiqrVdQ0FvGg5QOeOHAAhADcpjT8-JQEeBwCwGwoPuoo2GwSYHAQ8gAWnFxM2qgYWDZEtiwGjOJSpQSyhbolMkaOUABuKGzqFFCRlMmp6Zk5eQWIRXq1thwQAO5ikvpy5HSMAERrADS9hg72wVAA9IcA8gDS-SlpGVm53GM6xUsE03MLNc2yKwxQG9tI6y2vF29n2R0OUHOlCiMTiCSSVyGt1GADkIG0IGhys0qotarIZhi0IZWh0uj1+ANrsM7vk0UTXvNqs8vqtflsdnsDsdYGg0OgoJdBjcRvd6ZjGe8Wd9Af9ZcCueDefy0EA)

If your class is contra-variant you can use `never`  and any instantiation of `SomeStuff` will be compatible with it as `SomeStuff<never>` will be the base class of all instantiations:

```
type ElaborateStuff = {
    a: string
}
class SomeStuff<T extends ElaborateStuff> {
    getStuff = (v: T): void  => null!
}

function doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(stuff: SomeStuff<ElaborateStuff>): void { }

doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // error
doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>()); //error

function doSimpleThingsNever(stuff: SomeStuff<never>): void { }

doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // ok 
doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>());// ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNgQwEYHsBODgQMrAK4BmBUAvFAN4BQUNUCAXFAM7BoCWAdgOaUC+lAY0RMmUbCgC2OfEQA8AFSgQAHlg4ATUfGTpM0wgQB8FarS4RgANVwGAFAEpGiqrVdQ0FvGg5QOeOHAAhADcpjT8-JQEeBwCwGwoPuoo2GwSYHAQ8gAWnFxM2qgYWDZEtiwGjOJSpQSyhbolMkaOUABuKGzqFFCRlMmp6Zk5eQWIRXq1thwQAO5ikvpy5HSMAERrADS9hg72wVAA9IcA8gDS-SlpGVm53GM6xUsE03MLNc2yKwxQG9tI6y2vF29n2R0OUHOlCiMTiCSSVyGt1GADkIG0IGhys0qotarIZhi0IZWh0uj1+ANrsM7vk0UTXvNqs8vqtflsdnsDsdYGg0OgoJdBjcRvd6ZjGe8Wd9Af9ZcCueDefy0EA)

If your type is invariant however, you can only use `any`. Lint rules are useful but **can be ignored** and there are good use cases for `any`, such as in this case. However you should be aware this is type not safe, so you should not rely on the compiler to check any operation in which the type parameter is involed:

```
type ElaborateStuff = {
    a: string
}
class SomeStuff<T extends ElaborateStuff> {
    getStuff = (v: T): T  => {
        v.a.big(); // error if a is not there
        return v;
    }
}

function doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(stuff: SomeStuff<ElaborateStuff>): void { }

doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // error
doSimpleThingsElaborateStuff(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>()); //error

function doSimpleThingsNever(stuff: SomeStuff<never>): void { }

doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // error
doSimpleThingsNever(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>());// error


function doSimpleThingsAny(stuff: SomeStuff<any>): void {
    stuff.getStuff({}) // will trigger an error
    stuff.getStuff({ a: ""}).foo // error on foo access
}

doSimpleThingsAny(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", }>()); // ok
doSimpleThingsAny(new SomeStuff<{ a: "", b: "",}>()); // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNgQwEYHsBODgQMrAK4BmBUAvFAN4BQUNUCAXFAM7BoCWAdgOaUC+lAY0RMmUbCgC2OfEQA8AFSgQAHlg4ATUfGTpM0wgQB8FarS4RguA6SgAKAG6N5ASic0SxqrW9R7AOgQ-JDYuW2cAbigAeiilNDR0KDZiBCTRDhRgKGAACwg0CFMfKAL8NA5fcKKofn5KAjwOAWA2FAr1FGw2CTA4CHkczi4mbVQMLCsiWxYDRnEpSYJZUd0JmSNXXxQ2dQoaykoOrp6+gaGRxDG9RdsOCAB3MUl9OXI6RgAiD4AaGsMwiLRWL5BJoQ6dbq9fqDbgXHTjF4EW4PJ4LdayN4MKBfX5IT4-Xj-ZyAmIg9AHBpNFptKBHSGnGHDAByEHs+Wm6zmz0WsjubLQhk29m2uzedTpJ2h5xZ-ORj3miIx72xPz+AMiMTioPBxyhZ1hMvZd3l3PRmPxuIthPVmrJYIpjWarXaEMl+uGAEEOCAObNUYqEN7BYxhTsTN4ZkQ-OZLOtbOReM4gVB7mw4HBsuwuOY0HQKnbqpGCNGLDdzSrE34CCgUMm7VAadXawgBAIICI+AcJXrGUwvT7jf6eeWcWriRrYigANY6+lS2H9uVDs3K0d4lXfa3j5PToA)